# How can i adapt this highcharts code (sparkline charts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to use the sparkline chart model from highcharts demos, but in my local website.

I'm copying the code from codepen (link below), but is not working...

https://www.highcharts.com/samples/codepen/highcharts/demo/sparkline

Javascript returns this error in the browser console:

```
$td.highcharts is not a function
```

Probably this issue is related to my Highcharts version because using the latest one solves the problem.

The line where I get the error is this one:

```
$td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
        series: [{
            data: data,
            pointStart: 1
        }],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
        },
        chart: chart
    });
```

I'm trying to adapt It, to find out if it can work with my version of Highcharts (2.5.7).

I know that this solution is wrong because it gives me other errors, but  I beleive that It could be something the right way:

```
Highcharts.SparkLine($td,{
  series: [{
    data: data,
    pointStart: 1
  }],
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
  },
  chart: chart
});
```

Someone has some idea about how can I adapt the function in a right way? And if this is not the correct solution, what can I do?

Sorry for my english and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because of the old Highcharts version.

However, it can be resolved by adding the default HighchartsAdapter for jQuery from the newer version. Check demo posted below with Highcharts 2.3.5 used.

```
$.fn.highcharts = function() {
        var constr = 'Chart', // default constructor
          args = arguments,
          options,
          ret,
          chart;

        if (isString(args[0])) {
          constr = args[0];
          args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);
        }
        options = args[0];

        // Create the chart
        if (options !== UNDEFINED) {
          /*jslint unused:false*/
          options.chart = options.chart || {};
          options.chart.renderTo = this[0];
          chart = new Highcharts[constr](options, args[1]);
          ret = this;
          /*jslint unused:true*/
        }

        // When called without parameters or with the return argument, get a predefined chart
        if (options === UNDEFINED) {
          ret = charts[attr(this[0], 'data-highcharts-chart')];
        }

        return ret;
      };
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vcrg163y/